# How to install Grunt plugin properly

Tags: gruntjs, npm, bower

Sorry, I'm newbie in npm-bower-grunt services. Maybe this question is stupid, but I can't find solution in google.

So, I have installed single page app based on npm/bower/grunt/angular.js

In the root I have gruntfile.js with this code

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
var gtx = require('gruntfile-gtx').wrap(grunt);

gtx.loadAuto();

var gruntConfig = require('./grunt');
gruntConfig.package = require('./package.json');

gtx.config(gruntConfig);

// We need our bower components in order to develop
gtx.alias('build:standardversion', [

    'compass:standardversion',
    ...

]);

gtx.finalise();
```

};

Else I have file grunt/compass.js with:

```
module.exports = {
standardversion: {
    options: {
        config: 'STANDARD/master/config.rb'
    }
}
```

};

Then in bower_components folder I have gruntfiles for each plugin with code something like:

```
    'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        karma: {
           ...
        },

        uglify: {
           ...
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'karma',
        'uglify'
    ]);
};
```

So now I have to install css-flip plugin from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-css-flip

I installed it with npm and now I don't know where to write a task for this.
Am I need to create new file in bower_components or somewhere else?

Please tell me or give me a link to understand it properly

Thanx

Comment: i am having same issue, if you have resolved could you please tell me how did u add new pluglin in gruntfile-gtx